# Maximum Likelihood Estimate With Factorial

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

How do you find the maximum likelihood estimate of this function?

$$P_x(k;\theta) = \frac{\theta^{2k} e^{-\theta^2}}{k!}$$

I'm really just having trouble with the factorial part... really not sure how to approach this problem.

Thanks

Comment: This is Poisson with parameter called $\theta^2$ instead of $\lambda.$ Answer by @spaceisdarkgreen is useful (+!). Maybe see Wikipedia, under parameter estimation. Unclear from your question, but I suppose you want $n=1.$ Don't 'borrow trouble' fretting about $\theta !,$ irrelevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likelihood function you're maximizing is a function of $\theta$ so the $k!$ is just a multiplicative constant. It has no effect on what value of $\theta$ maximizes the function. (One way to see this is that it will clear when you take the derivative and set it to zero.)

Comment: Oh... right. Well, what if it were $\theta!$ instead?

Comment: @user3026388 It's not a likelihood function anymore, but it makes sense to ask what the is the maximum of $f(\theta) = \theta^{2k}e^{-\theta^2}/\theta!.$ Then you're in a tougher situation. At least we can see by the form of the function that there's a unique positive maximum. You can find it numerically for a given value of $k,$ or perhaps use the Gamma function and its derivative and then approximate the maximizing $\theta$ by an expansion of those. It actually helps that $\theta$'s an integer, cause then you just need to get close and test the integers near there for which one's biggest.

Comment: In case it got lost in the noise above the simple answer is there's no nice closed form solution